# Python Tkinter Scrollbar Shaky Scrolling

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, resize, scrollbar

***Introduction:*** My Python Tkinter application is designed to have a scrollbar on the side so that if the window is resized, the application can still be viewed via the scrollbar. I do this by putting a frame with all my content inside a canvas, with a scrollbar controlling the canvas. On window resize, I have a function called resizeCanvas which resizes the canvas.

***Problem:*** After I resize the window, the scrollbar sort of works but it seems to jump around and fidget like its having a seizure. However, at initialization the scroll bar works smoothly. So resizing the window seems to be the problem. ***Any suggestions on why the scroll bar is behaving like this?***

***Application Hierarchy:***

- Tkinter root

  - frame (just a container for the canvas)

    - canvas (scroll bar is attached to this canvas)

      - frame (content is in this frame)

***NOTE: Python 2.7.2***

***Code Snippit:***

```
    myframe=Frame(root,width=winx,height=winy)
    myframe.place(x=0,y=0)
    canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(myframe,width=winx,height=winy)
    frame = Frame(canvas,width=winx,height=winy)
    myscrollbar=Scrollbar(myframe,orient="vertical")
    myscrollbar.configure(command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

    myscrollbar.pack(side="left",fill="y")
    canvas.pack(side="left")
    canvas.create_window((0,0),window=frame,anchor='nw')
    frame.bind("<Configure>", initializeCanvas)
    bind("<Configure>", resizeCanvas)

def initializeCanvas(self, event):
   canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"),width=winx,height=winy)

def resizeCanvas(self, event):
    update()
    cwidth = self.winfo_width()
    cheight = self.winfo_height()
    canvas.config(width=cwidth, height=cheight)
```

***Entire Code:***

```
import sys
#external python files are in the includes folder
sys.path.insert(0, 'includes')

import webbrowser
import os
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
import ConfigParser
from ttk import *
import tkFont
import Tix

# configurations held in this variable
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
# pady padding for create buttons
py = 15
# padx padding for create buttons
px = 5
# padding on left side for indenting elements
indentx = 25
winx = 815
winy = 515
# array to hold features
FEATURES =['']


# wrapper class for GUI
class AppTk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.settings = "./settings/settings.cfg"
        self.initialize_gui()
        self.minsize(winx, 100)
        sizex = winx
        sizey = winy
        posx  = 100
        posy  = 100
        self.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

        try:
            self.iconbitmap('./imgs/favicon.ico')
        except Exception, e:
            print "\n****Error occurred (GUI_MBD_File_Creator.init):  favicon not found!"

    # Setup grid of elements in GUI
    # action: on start of application
    def initialize_gui(self):

        # ----------------------------------------------------
        # START Settings frame initialization
        # ----------------------------------------------------
        self.myframe=Frame(self,width=winx,height=winy)
        self.myframe.place(x=0,y=0)
        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self.myframe,width=winx,height=winy)
        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas,width=winx,height=winy)
        self.myscrollbar=Scrollbar(self.myframe,orient="vertical")
        self.myscrollbar.configure(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.myscrollbar.set)

        self.myscrollbar.pack(side="left",fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left")
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.frame,anchor='nw')
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>",self.initializeCanvas)
        self.bind("<Configure>",self.resizeCanvas)


        frameFont = tkFont.Font(size=13, weight=tkFont.BOLD)

        self.frameSettings = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="Settings: fill these out first", relief="groove", borderwidth="3", font=frameFont)
        self.frameSettings.grid(sticky="EW", padx=px, pady=(5,15))

        labelSpreadsheet = Label(self.frameSettings, text="1. Spreadsheet Path:")
        labelSpreadsheet.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W', padx=(indentx,0))
        variableSpreadsheet = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entrySpreadsheet = Entry(self.frameSettings, textvariable=variableSpreadsheet, width=90, state=Tkinter.DISABLED)
        self.entrySpreadsheet.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='W', padx=px, pady=5)
        self.entrySpreadsheet.svar = variableSpreadsheet
        buttonSpreadsheet = Button(self.frameSettings, text="Browse...")
        buttonSpreadsheet.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='W', padx=(0,10))

        labelPath = Label(self.frameSettings, text="2. Root Save Path:")
        labelPath.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W', padx=(indentx,0))
        variablePath = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entryPath = Entry(self.frameSettings, textvariable=variablePath, width=90, state=Tkinter.DISABLED)
        self.entryPath.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='W', padx=px, pady=(5,10))
        self.entryPath.svar = variablePath
        buttonPath = Button(self.frameSettings, text="Browse...")
        buttonPath.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='W', padx=(0,10), pady=(0,5))

        # ----------------------------------------------------
        # START Creation Menu frame initialization
        # ----------------------------------------------------

        self.frameCreationIndividual = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="Feature Files Creation Menu", relief="groove", borderwidth="3", font=frameFont)
        self.frameCreationIndividual.grid(sticky="EW", padx=px, pady=(5,15))

        labelReq = Label(self.frameCreationIndividual, text="3. Feature(s):")
        labelReq.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NW', pady=(5,0), padx=(indentx,15))
        self.scrollbarReq = Scrollbar(self.frameCreationIndividual)
        self.scrollbarReq.grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=16, sticky="NSW", pady=(0,15),padx=(0,20))

        variableSelectAll = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkSelectAll = Checkbutton(self.frameCreationIndividual, text = "Select All", variable = variableSelectAll, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        self.checkSelectAll.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='NE', padx=px, pady=(5,0))
        self.checkSelectAll.svar = variableSelectAll

        labelReq = Label(self.frameCreationIndividual, text="4. Files:")
        labelReq.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky='NW', pady=(5,0), padx=15)

        variableIndividualFFS = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkIndividualFFS = Checkbutton(self.frameCreationIndividual, text = "Create Feature File", variable = variableIndividualFFS, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        self.checkIndividualFFS.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky='NW', padx=15)
        self.checkIndividualFFS.svar = variableIndividualFFS

        variableIndividualSFS = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkIndividualSFS = Checkbutton(self.frameCreationIndividual, text = "Create SubFeature Files", variable = variableIndividualSFS, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        self.checkIndividualSFS.grid(row=2, column=5, sticky='NW', padx=15)
        self.checkIndividualSFS.svar = variableIndividualSFS

        variableIndividualDO = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkIndividualDO = Checkbutton(self.frameCreationIndividual, text = "Create Doc Outline", variable = variableIndividualDO, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        self.checkIndividualDO.grid(row=3, column=5, sticky='NW', padx=15)
        self.checkIndividualDO.svar = variableIndividualDO

        variableIndividualDWR = Tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkIndividualDWR = Checkbutton(self.frameCreationIndividual, text = "Create Doc With Requirements", variable = variableIndividualDWR, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
        self.checkIndividualDWR.grid(row=4, column=5, sticky='NW', padx=(15,30))
        self.checkIndividualDWR.svar = variableIndividualDWR

        self.buttonIndividualAll = Button(self.frameCreationIndividual, text="Create...", width=43)
        self.buttonIndividualAll.grid(row=1, column=6, rowspan=4, sticky='NESW', padx=px)

        # ----------------------------------------------------
        # START Entire System Creation frame initialization
        # ----------------------------------------------------

        self.frameCreationSystem = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="System Creation Menu", relief="groove", borderwidth="3", font=frameFont)
        self.frameCreationSystem.grid(sticky="EW", padx=px, pady=15)

        self.buttonLAIF = Button(self.frameCreationSystem, text="Create Layers/App Integration Files", width=35)
        self.buttonLAIF.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky='NESW', ipady=5, padx=(indentx,0), pady=(16,8))

        self.buttonDO = Button(self.frameCreationSystem, text="Create Entire Doc Outline")
        self.buttonDO.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky='NESW', ipady=5, padx=(indentx,0), pady=(8,10))

        # ----------------------------------------------------
        # START Feature Tab Creation Frame initialization
        # ----------------------------------------------------

        self.frameCreationNew = Tkinter.LabelFrame(self.frame, text="Feature Tab Creation Menu", relief="groove", borderwidth="3", font=frameFont)
        self.frameCreationNew.grid(sticky="EW", padx=px, pady=(15,5))

        labelIssueSpreadsheet = Label(self.frameCreationNew, text="2. Feature Spreadsheet Path:")
        labelIssueSpreadsheet.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W', padx=(indentx,0))
        variableIssueSpreadsheet = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entryIssueSpreadsheet = Entry(self.frameCreationNew, textvariable=variableIssueSpreadsheet, width=83, state=Tkinter.DISABLED)
        self.entryIssueSpreadsheet.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='W', padx=px, pady=5)
        self.entryIssueSpreadsheet.svar = variableIssueSpreadsheet
        buttonIssueSpreadsheet = Button(self.frameCreationNew, text="Browse...")
        buttonIssueSpreadsheet.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='W')

        labelFeatureTab = Label(self.frameCreationNew, text="3. Feature Name:")
        labelFeatureTab.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W', padx=(indentx,0))
        variableFeatureTab = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entryFeatureTab = Entry(self.frameCreationNew, textvariable=variableFeatureTab, width=83)
        self.entryFeatureTab.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='W', padx=px, pady=5)
        self.entryFeatureTab.svar = variableFeatureTab

        labelFeatureAbbrv = Label(self.frameCreationNew, text="4. Feature Abbreviation:")
        labelFeatureAbbrv.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='W', padx=(indentx,0))
        variableFeatureAbbrv = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entryFeatureAbbrv = Entry(self.frameCreationNew, textvariable=variableFeatureAbbrv, width=83)
        self.entryFeatureAbbrv.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='W', padx=px, pady=5)
        self.entryFeatureAbbrv.svar = variableFeatureAbbrv

        self.buttonNewFeature = Button(self.frameCreationNew, text="Create Feature Tab", width=35)
        self.buttonNewFeature.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan =2, sticky='NWS', ipady=5, pady=(8,10), padx=(indentx,0))

    # ----------------------------------------------------
    # START general purpose methods
    # ----------------------------------------------------

    def initializeCanvas(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"),width=winx,height=winy)

    def resizeCanvas(self, event):
        self.update()
        cwidth = self.winfo_width()
        cheight = self.winfo_height()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"), width=cwidth, height=cheight)

# ----------------------------------------------------
# Initialize application
# ----------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = AppTk(None)
    app.title("MBD File Creator")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Interesting problem, but I don't think I can diagnose it without a complete code sample that exhibits the problem. I'm just getting `IndentationError` running what you've provided so far.

Comment: My application is rather large, I can see what I can do to trim it down and post it here.

Comment: Trimmed code added, should be runnable, thanks.

Comment: When I run your code and try to resize the window I get an endless cascade of errors.

Comment: Hmm, I tested the trimmed done code and it worked for me. Are you using Python 2.7.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there may be other errors, you have one very critical flaw: you are creating a binding for the `<Configure>` event to `self`. Because `self` is the instance of the root window, *every widget you create inherits this binding*. Your `resizeCanvas` method is literally being called hundreds of times at startup, and hundreds of times when the window is resized.

You also have the problem where you are calling `update` in an event handler. As a general rule, this is bad. In effect, it's like calling `mainloop` in that it will not return  until all events are processed. If your code causes more events to be processed (such as reconfiguring a window and causing the `<configure>` event to fire, you end up in a recursive loop.

You probably need to remove the calls to `self.update()` and/or replace them with the less dangerous `self.update_idletasks()`. You also need to either remove the `<Configure>` binding on `self`, or in the method you need to check for which widget caused the event to fire (ie: check that the event.widget is the root window).

Comment: As you can probably notice, I'm new to Python, and new to Tkinter. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: All excellent advice. "remove the calls to `self.update()`" by itself appears to fix the jerky scrolling problem.

Comment: YOU MIRACLE WORKER. Removing self.update() fixed the scrolling. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try first to save the `canvas.create_window` to a variable as following:

```
self.windows_item = canvas.create_window((0,0),window=frame,anchor='nw')
```

then at the end of `resizeCanvas` to call the following method:

```
def update(self):
    "Update the canvas and the scrollregion"
    self.update_idletasks()
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(self.windows_item))
```

Hope it helps!

Most of it found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47985165/2160507